# How to add a bundle file ( created using ejs ) that renders in ejs node app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react/node app and i am using ejs like so:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EJS Is Fun</title>
    
    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap from a CDN) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body { padding-top:50px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="container">

<header>
  Hi header here !
</header>

<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>This is great</h1>
        <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    HI footer here.
</footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to add a script tag which basically added the main entry point of the react app. how do i do this ?

Basically when webpack loads the document on `npm run start` (i'am using create-react-app) the js bundle file are automatically added to the html document. similarly how can i add these bundled files to my ejs file ?

P.S.

- Webpack in dev mode does't really generate any physical files.
- the node and react are running on on different ports.